# Ability to multiple 1 row of existing column with another row of existing column in R to create a 3rd column

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column in the below data set column DPD roll over; wherein I want to calculate ratio based on value from row 1 in column DPD <29 and row 2 in column DPD 30 to 60 (eg: 30 / 55). Can anyone please help with answer? I am looking to do this in R

Month    DPD <29       DPD 30 to 60
May 12    55                25
Jun 12    60                30

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lead` to get the next value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(ratio = lead(`DPD 30 to 60`)/`DPD <29`)
```